# Returning a Promise, but getting 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I've read through the other examples of people getting this error on here, but I'm continuing to get the same error when trying to chain promises together.

In the code below, pegasus (the promise-based http library: https://github.com/typicode/pegasus) makes a call to an API, gets back some JSON, and returns a promise. I can process the data it returns back using the first `then` without an issue. This code is synchronous, and initially I wasn't returning a promise because I was under the impression that it wasn't necessary (and still might not be). In the code below I tried wrapping it in a promise anyway as that was a commonly offered solution for other similar questions on Stack Overflow, but that doesn't seem to have solved it either.

Still, I am getting the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` message.

```
var polygonGeo, centroidGeo;
var hexData = pegasus(hexUrl)
  .then(function(data, xhr) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var features = data.features;
      var polygons = features.filter(function(feature) {
        return feature.properties.kind === 'Hexagon';
      });
      var centroids = features.filter(function(feature) {
        return feature.properties.kind === 'Centroid';
      });

      polygonGeo = $.extend(true, {}, data);
      centroidGeo = $.extend(true, {}, data);

      polygonGeo.features = polygons;
      centroidGeo.features = centroids;
      if (typeof polygonGeo !== 'undefined' &&
          typeof centroidGeo !== 'undefined') {
        resolve();
      }
    });
}).then(function() {
  console.log('It never reaches here.');
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(Error(error));
});
```

Any idea where I might be going wrong?

Comment: In which of the lines do you get that type error?

Comment: What does `pegasus` return? *Edit:* [This](https://github.com/typicode/pegasus) suggests it returns a promise, so should be okay.

Comment: "*The code in this then is synchronous, but I've wrapped it in a promise*" makes no sense. Just `return` the data from the callback, or `throw` if you failed to compute the data. (Which, btw, is just the case you missed, your promise might stay forever pending)

Comment: I don't see any reason your `then` callback should be creating a promise. There's no async code in it.

Comment: I should have explained better: I initially wasn't returning a promise because I thought I shouldn't need to, and I was getting this error. Reading other solutions to this error, the response was 'you are not returning a promise' so I tried that and it also returned the same error.

Comment: @Bergi I get it at the second then line: `}).then(function() {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `pegasus` doesn't implement A+/Promises. Or, really, any kind of promises in the generally-accepted sense.

If we look at its [source code](https://github.com/typicode/pegasus/blob/master/src/pegasus.js), we can see that its `then` function doesn't return anything:

```
function pegasus(a, xhr) {
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // ...lines omitted...

  xhr.onreadystatechange = xhr.then = function(onSuccess, onError, cb, data) {
      // ...lines omitted, there is no `return` anywhere, at all...
  };

  // Send
  xhr.send();

  // Return request
  return xhr;
}
```

It's creating an XHR object, then adding a `then` property to it which is a function which is <s>nothing short of bizarre</s> not a proper `then` in the Promises sense, and returns that XHR object.

A proper `then` function returns a new promise. Neither the `pegasus` function nor its `then` returns a promise, at all.

Comment: That library is a joke, right? It doesn't even implement a *thenable*. They've got good reason to put the word "promise" in quotes in their docs.

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, I certainly wouldn't use it, for all kinds of reasons, not least that `then` thing, using a function argument as a variable, conflating the `onreadystatechange` callback and the `then` function the *user* of the lib is supposed to use to hook up a handler...

Answer (score 1):

@Brideau sorry for that, `then` may be confusing. As @T.J. explained, it's not a real Promise. I'll emphasise that part in the `README`.

About not using Promises, the idea of Pegasus is that the faster it loads, the faster it can start making requests.

That's why I'm not using a Promise polyfill. It's to make the library as small as possible. I'm only supporting `GET` + `JSON` requests too for the same reason.

Regarding the "weird" code style, I'm using
[Byte-saving Techniques](https://github.com/jed/140bytes/wiki/Byte-saving-techniques). That's why, for example, function parameters are used as variable placeholders.

So Pegasus should be used at the begin, but after that you may use other libraries to make more complex requests.

I hope it makes things a bit clearer :)